# Grails 3 Unit Testing: How do you do mockFor, createMock, and demands in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.0.9

I'm upgrading an application from Grails 2.4.4 to Grails 3.0.9, and I can't find any information on how to do mockFor, createMock, and demands in Grails 3.

I used to do things like this:

```
fooService = mockFor(FooService)
controller.fooService = fooService.createMock()

fooService.demand.barMethod() { a,b ->
}
```

But it looks like 'mockFor' is simply gone, even from the documentation. What's the Grails 3 way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

I don't want to rewrite thousands of tests written with the Grails 'mockFor' style to the Spock style of interactions, so I came up with this solution:

- replace mockFor() with new MockFor()
- replace createMock() with proxyInstance()
- move the calls to fooBean.fooService = fooService.proxyInstance() to *after* the demands

With no further changes, this "just works" in Grails 3.

Comment: The answer will depend on which testing framework you are using, which isn't indicated in your question.  Are you using Spock?  JUnit?  Something else?

Comment: I've been using the mockFor+createMock+demand pattern from Grails 1.3.7 (GrailsUnitTestCase JUnit style) to Grails 2.4.4 (Specification Spock style).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Spock](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/Interactions) by default:

```
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test if mocking works"() {
        given:
        def fooService = Mock(FooService)
        fooService.barMethod(_, _) >> {a, b ->
            return a - b
        }

        when:
        def result = fooService.barMethod(5, 4)

        then:
        result == 1
    }
}

class FooService {
    int barMethod(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was enough for me to figure it out, thanks much.

Comment: Check out the Groovy solution I came up with (updated in the original post).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this might come in handy :)

Answer (score 6):

I was also upgrading a lot of tests from grails 2 that used `mockFor` and used a similar approach which HypeMK outlined:

1. add import for groovy's MockFor:
   `import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor`
2. rename `mockFor` to `new MockFor`
3. rename `createMock()` to `proxyInstance()`
4. remove calls to `verify()`

Comment: Answer working fine for Junit test-cases in Grails 3.2.4